# .htaccess redirect /dir to /index?page=dir

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm looking to redirect `example.com/subdir` to `example.com?page=subdir`, while still keeping `example.com/subdir` in the URL. This way, I can dynamically "create pages" with different get requests. I've gotten down how to do this, but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent `example.com/subdir/subdir` from causing assets to load improperly. Here's my current code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect /page.php, /page.html, and /page.htm to /page
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html|htm)\/*$ /$1 [R,L]
# If the page is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Internally redirect /page to /index.php?page=page
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,END]
# Redirect /index to /
Redirect /index /
```

Comment: [Apache Module mod_rewrite Documenation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keep only these rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.(?:php|html)[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing to avoid old cache.